# How to update patch of mysql 5.6.14 to mysql 5.6.28 or more?

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat, patch

I have mysql server on Linux Redhat 6.4 and I want to upgrade it to mysql server 5.6.28. I googled number of sites, all I am getting is upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6 or 5.6 to 5.7.

Note: There is no internet available on redhat but I can transfer rpm.

Please let me know how I can upgrade the patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got no reply but did it somehow. 
Easy way- 
download required client, server and share rpm file from mysql's download page and use rpm upgrade(-Uvh) option.
That's it.